# datagridHeader is being smaller when the scrollbar is appearing to fit the data

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6R7u.jpg)I am using this datagrid, when the data is few the header is Nice, but when the data rows is many so the scrollbar is visible and the header row is shorter, so how can i let it not short even if the scrollbar is here? My Problem image

```
<DataGrid Margin="10"
          HeadersVisibility="All" 
          FlowDirection="{StaticResource DirectFlowDirection}"  
          Foreground="{DynamicResource MainBrush}"  
          Background="{DynamicResource DataGridBackgroundBrush}"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource Rows}" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="datagrid_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>-->
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="1*"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridHeaderColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridHeaderForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>MyColumns here</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want the header row keep in the entire window width

Answer (score 0):

Re templating with the scroll viewer just round the itemspresenter looks possible, but you already have styling in your project.

The template is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

If your concern is purely cosmetic you could consider putting a small blue rectangle on top of the top left corner to sort of fill in that area. Maybe make it hittestable false.